# How to set file expiry

Tags: azure-data-lake, u-sql

In Cosmos SCOPE script, we can set the stream/file expiration date using the following code:

```
OUTPUT Catalog
TO SSTREAM @Output
WITH STREAMEXPIRY @ExpirationInDays;
```

What is the equivalent syntax in U-SQL?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right now U-SQL does not provide this option (managing expirations is on our roadmap though). The store just recently introduced the ability to set expiration on files. Please file a feature request at http://aka.ms/adlfeedback and let us know if you prefer it as part of the language or as part of a more policy-based management solution.